# Is this directory structure suitable for an AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs

Hey I have structure of angularjs files :

> project/
>
> -bin
>
> -model
>
> -node_modules
>
> -public
>
> -routes
>
> -views
> app.js,  package.json,  package-lock.json

inside file public is:

> -images
>
> -javascripts
>
> -stylesheets

and inside javascripts I have :

- board (inside boardController)
- boards (inside boardsController)
- components (inside navbar/navbar-components.js  and navbar-template.html)

And I would ask do I have good this structure files or I should changes something?, I am during processing the project on components, its reason why I ask that do I have good or I Should transfer file components to other or I should change names ??

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is ok. But you are missing some details. For example, in general we should use a folder named `app`. Here will be everything related to YOUR app, and not config files or node modules.

Another missed, Is the module concept, your views should be inside your board, boards, and componets. Why? It makes easier find where the files should be, edit them and even easier grow it up and scalate it.

Here you can find a better structure for your project:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Which is:

```
app/
-- index.html
-- shared/   // acts as reusable components or partials of our site
-- -- sidebar/
-- -- -- sidebarDirective.js
-- -- -- sidebarView.html
-- -- article/
-- -- -- articleDirective.js
-- -- -- articleView.html
-- components/   // each component is treated as a mini Angular app
-- -- home/
-- -- -- homeController.js
-- -- -- homeService.js
-- -- -- homeView.html
-- -- blog/
-- -- -- blogController.js
-- -- -- blogService.js
-- -- -- blogView.html
-- -- app.module.js
-- -- app.routes.js
assets/
-- img/      // Images and icons for your app
-- css/      // All styles and style related files (SCSS or LESS files)
-- js/       // JavaScript files written for your app that are not for angular
-- libs/     // Third-party libraries such as jQuery, Moment, Underscore, etc.
```

In the page you can read further about each folder/idea. If your project will be BIG you can read the recomendations, too.

Another good reference is Angular (Angular 2+), where we have pages in an specific file inside our project, and are the pages with not component relation (Like Home, About and stuff) And we have component for the re-usable stuff as you described.

Answer (score 1):

I generally follow the [Angular JS styleguide from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#naming). I've had success with that application structure for about 3-4 years now. It's basically like jose said; you keep your application code - js, views, tests, etc. - in a directory called `/app` and, then divide your code into folders according to modules.

So say, you have three distinct parts of your application: account, layout and boards. Then you'd structure your application like this:

```
app/
    account/
        account.module.js
        account.component.js
        account.component.spec.js
        account.component.html
    layout/
        layout.module.js
        navbar/
            navbar.component.js
            navbar.component.spec.js
            navbar.component.html
    boards/
        boards.module.js
        boards.component.js
        boards.component.spec.js
        boards.component.html
    app.module.js
    app.config.js
```

etc.

Naturally, the exact structure depends on how you structure your modules, but this is the basics of a great way to structure your application.

The rest of the files (static assets, configuration, build scripts, etc.) sits in the root along with the `app/` folder. So something like this:

```
app/
assets/
    images/
    fonts/
    styles/
node_modules/
dist/
package.json
index.html
karma.conf.js
gulpfile.js
```

etc.

I suggest you checkout the styleguide. A lot of helpful tips in there.

Comment: Hey thanks, what If I have 10subcomponents in for example navbar ? so I will create navbar / navbar.mobule.js navbar.component.js navbar.component.html <<----- this is main so what now if I have inside him 10subcomponents where I should put them inside? how is it supposed to look like?

Comment: In the end it's up to what you find most convenient. If I only have 3-4 sub components, I usually keep the files in the same folder-level as their parent. If I have more, I usually give each component their own sub folder to live in. So for instance `navbar/logo/logo.component.js`, `navbar/loginmenu/loginmenu.component.js`, `navbar/mainmenu/mainmenu.component.js`, etc. Whatever structure makes the cohesion of the components most apparent, basically. If that makes sense.

Comment: hey can u look here ? https://imgur.com/a/M5eu8 i put inside subcomponents but what with main component in this file navbar? if I have navbar(main folder) I cant set inside navbar folder again:D or it should be there? navbar/navbar ? Or leave it as it in photo?

Comment: What you have in that image looks fine to me, so you're certainly on the right path.

Comment: But it annoys me somehow that these three things are not wrapped, can it put into a folder with the name "main"? will be good? what do you think? or to leave it as it is?: D

Comment: I'd leave it as is. If the three `navbar` files is in a folder called `navbar`, then they should be immediately visible as soon as you open that folder - not hidden in a subfolder. If you hide it in another subfolder, it would be harder to find the relevant filer for someone else looking at the project, or future you. :-) It would also be harder to discern which folders contains subcomponents to the `navbar` component.